# Click element within Data Grid Column Header

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have applied a custom style to my DataGrid's column headers. Here is a simplified version of it:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Grid>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <Grid>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <ContentPresenter Margin="5 0 5 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                <Image IsHitTestVisible="True" Source="pin.png">
                                    <Image.InputBindings>
                                        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{x:Static myView:MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                    </Image.InputBindings>
                                </Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" Style="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderResizeThumb}"/>
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderResizeThumb}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I am struggling to get the command to fire when clicking the image. Is there something I am missing? Is there a different way that I can fire a command when clicking an element (i.e. an image) within the DataGridColumnHeader?

Some more details:
MyCommand is defined in the Window's CommandBindings. I have not included this code here. I have other commands defined similarly for other elements (i.e. DataGridCell) that work OK. It seems there is something specific to the way the DataGridColumnHeader element that prevents the command to be fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're binding to the type `MyCommand` under  xmlns `myView`; instead, you should be binding to an instance of `MyCommand` (assuming class `MyCommand` implements `ICommand`). You may consider implementing singleton here. Or you could define a static instance of `MyCommand` anywhere.

Comment: I do not think that the problem I am facing is related to the way I specify the command. I have updated the question to include a bit more details. Thanks.

Comment: @tolism7 Are you sure `ICommand.CanExecute` returns `true`? or is it not even being hit?

Comment: A few seconds before reading your comment here I felt like a muppet after realizing that the command was not being hit due to an inherited CanExecute returning false. You are right and thanks for the suggestion. There is nothing wrong with the way the Style is defined. What is wrong is that I am working on Sunday night :-)